# How to stop visual studio solution settings passing to another in a batch script call

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have two solutions:

- ParentSolution.sln
- ChildSolution.sln

..and they have some common projects they both reference.

In a pre-build step `ParentSolution.sln` calls a batch file which calls msbuild to build the child solution (this is done so the parent can ingest the result of the child build into it's manfiest so it can be deploy an upgrade on an embedded device).

The batch script looks some thing like this:

```
msbuild.exe "ChildSolution.sln" -p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 -maxCpuCount -t:clean
msbuild.exe "ChildSolution.sln" -p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 -maxCpuCount
```

For some reason though, the call to clean the child seems to wipe out the parent solution's builds of all the shared projects.

Output directories are as follows for all projects:

- Output directory: `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`
- Intermediate Directory: `$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`

I've tried adjusting local directories, calling `vcvars64.bat` in the child but nothing seems to prevent this.

We're using visual studio 2019 if that makes a difference.

Short of making these completely independent processes, is there any way to fully separate the child build so it doesn't wipe out the parent? Some environment variable visual studio is picking up from the parent instance maybe?

**--Edit--**

Just to clarify we have something like this as a folder structure:

```cpp
Common\
  CommonProject1\
ParentSolution
  ParentProject\
  x64\
    Release\
      CommonProject1.dll // This gets wiped out...
ChildSolution            // ...when this is cleaned via the batch call from ParentSolution
  ChildProject\
  x64\
    Release\
      CommonProject1.dll
```

Comment: Does the child solution effectively contain the referenced projects, and/or how are they referenced exactly? And what project types are these?

Comment: C++-CLI projects and yes, the common projects are included in both solutions and referenced from both parent and child projects.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then by cleaning the solution, since it has the common projects. What would work is cleaning all main i.e. non-referenced projects manually with `msbuild project /t:clean /p:Platform=x64;BuildProjectReferences=False` , that last bit is what makes msbuild clean only the project itself. But then you'll have to keep a list of those main projects somehow.

Comment: Seems odd that the child solution which targets a different solution output directory cleans off the parent solution directory. The since the common projects reference the solution output I'd expected them to be targetting two different folders

Comment: Ah, I missed that clarification. So to be clear: when building first your child project builds, then the parent, and that parent is also going to build the shared projects separately? But with the same intermediate directory as the child did perhaps? And does cleaning of the child actually remove ChildProject/x64/release/CommonProject1.dll? How is 'referenced project' implemented exactly? All in all, we'd basically need a complete repro because there are still many other questions I could ask..

Comment: But: I'm thinking the file tracker might be at play here. Can you test that? Do a build, then manually delete the .tlog files/directory in the CommonProject1's intermediate directory (`IntDir`), then clean the child, it might leave the last (i.e. parent) output alone.

Answer (score 1):

`Clean` target is the default target in .NET build system. It will delete all intermediate and final build outputs. From my test results, it will delete the shared projects referenced from both parent and child projects.

To avoid wiping out shared projects, here are workarounds you can try.

1.Use Nuget package instead of project reference.

You can use `dotnet pack` command to package your shared project(e.g:CommonProject1) into a nuget package.(e.g:CommonProject1.1.0.0.nupkg).And then use `PackageReference` to refer this package. The call to clean the child will not wipe out the CommonProject1.dll files.

2.Use `IncrementalClean` instead of `Clean`.

```
msbuild.exe "ChildSolution.sln" -p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 -maxCpuCount -t:IncrementalClean
```

It removes files that were produced in a prior build but weren't produced in the current build.For more information, please refer to [default build targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2022#sdk-and-default-build-targets)

3.If you want to only clean intermediate(obj) and output files(bin) folders, you can custom target instead of default target `Clean`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <builtdir>\ChildSolution\bin</builtdir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomClean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(builtdir)" />
</Target>
```

```
msbuild.exe "ChildSolution.sln" -p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 -maxCpuCount -t:CustomClean
```

4.As stijn noted in above comment, you can use `BuildProjectReferences=False` to avoid checking that referenced projects are up to date.

Doc Referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022#list-of-common-properties-and-parameters

Hope it can help you.

Comment: That second point is interesting, didn't know that.